# Do you use TestContext in your unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I wonder, visual studio generates test classes with `TestContext` member as well as instance of it is passed to `ClassInitialize` method. But really, do you use this class? If so, what are the good examples where it's convenient/required to use it?

I have been writing tests for a while and never actually felt I needed to use `TestContext`. What about you?

Comment: From MSDN: [Using the TestContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TestContext` is normally used to provide an additional context, like required path information, web services, the `Page` object or some means of data access.

In my opinion, if a test needs this, we're not talking about unit tests at all. So if you don't find a reason to use `TestContext` in your unit tests, you're doing just fine I suppose.

When it comes to integration tests, this can come in very handy though.

Comment: I would like to point out that `TestContext` is the easiest (only?) way to access data during a [Data Driven](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527(v=vs.90).aspx) test.  I've used it with great success.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one I use it to obtain the locations of the test input/output directories and load/save files needed or generated by tests. Also to print messages to the test results, among other things.

I suppose it's possible to write unit tests without using the context at all, but I've never encountered that situation in a non-trivial testing scenario.